# Tensor flow objcet detecton Python If else kod

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, raspberry-pi3

I'm working on a project. in this project, our main aim is  If you put on cofia, safety glasses, and if you don't have a beard you can pass.  I trained the model and applied it on raspberry pi 3. I can see the results
but  I want to write on the screen  "You can pass" if 'cofia','glasses','no_beard' labels detect on the screen else   'You cannot pass'I'm sharing my code. Almost I tried all If methods in the file but I couldn't succeed.

Please help me

```
# 
# Import packages

import os

import argparse

import cv2

import numpy as np

import sys

import importlib.util



# Define and parse input arguments

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--modeldir', help='Folder the .tflite file is located in', required=True)

parser.add_argument('--graph', help='Name of the .tflite file, if different than detect.tflite', default='detect.tflite')

parser.add_argument('--labels', help='Name of the labelmap file, if different than labelmap.txt', default='labelmap.txt')

parser.add_argument('--threshold', help='Minimum confidence threshold for displaying detected objects', default=0.5)

parser.add_argument('--video', help='Name of the video file', default='test.mp4')

parser.add_argument('--edgetpu', help='Use Coral Edge TPU Accelerator to speed up detection', action='store_true')



args = parser.parse_args()



MODEL_NAME = args.modeldir

GRAPH_NAME = args.graph

LABELMAP_NAME = args.labels

VIDEO_NAME = args.video

min_conf_threshold = float(args.threshold)

use_TPU = args.edgetpu



# Import TensorFlow libraries

# If tflite_runtime is installed, import interpreter from tflite_runtime, else import from regular tensorflow

# If using Coral Edge TPU, import the load_delegate library

pkg = importlib.util.find_spec('tflite_runtime')

if pkg:

    from tflite_runtime.interpreter import Interpreter

    if use_TPU:

        from tflite_runtime.interpreter import load_delegate

else:

    from tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter import Interpreter

    if use_TPU:

        from tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter import load_delegate



# If using Edge TPU, assign filename for Edge TPU model

if use_TPU:

    # If user has specified the name of the .tflite file, use that name, otherwise use default 'edgetpu.tflite'

    if GRAPH_NAME == 'detect.tflite':

        GRAPH_NAME = 'edgetpu.tflite'



# Get path to current working directory

CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()



# Path to video file

VIDEO_PATH = os.path.join(CWD_PATH, VIDEO_NAME)



# Path to .tflite file, which contains the model that is used for object detection

PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH, MODEL_NAME, GRAPH_NAME)



# Path to label map file

PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH, MODEL_NAME, LABELMAP_NAME)



# Load the label map

with open(PATH_TO_LABELS, 'r') as f:

    labels = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]



# Have to do a weird fix for label map if using the COCO "starter model" from

# https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview

# First label is '???', which has to be removed.

if labels[0] == '???':

    del(labels[0])



# Load the Tensorflow Lite model.

# If using Edge TPU, use special load_delegate argument

if use_TPU:

    interpreter = Interpreter(model_path=PATH_TO_CKPT,

                              experimental_delegates=[load_delegate('libedgetpu.so.1.0')])

    print(PATH_TO_CKPT)

else:

    interpreter = Interpreter(model_path=PATH_TO_CKPT)



interpreter.allocate_tensors()



# Get model details

input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()

output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

height = input_details[0]['shape'][1]

width = input_details[0]['shape'][2]



floating_model = input_details[0]['dtype'] == np.float32



input_mean = 127.5

input_std = 127.5



# Check output layer name to determine if this model was created with TF2 or TF1,

# because outputs are ordered differently for TF2 and TF1 models

outname = output_details[0]['name']



if 'StatefulPartitionedCall' in outname:  # This is a TF2 model

    boxes_idx, classes_idx, scores_idx = 1, 3, 0

else:  # This is a TF1 model

    boxes_idx, classes_idx, scores_idx = 0, 1, 2



# Open video file

video = cv2.VideoCapture(VIDEO_PATH)

imW = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)

imH = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)



#label colors

label_colors = {

    "no_cofia": (0, 0, 255),    # Kırmızı

    "cofia": (0, 255, 0),       # Yeşil

    "no_beard": (0, 255, 0),    # Yeşil

    "beard": (0, 0, 255),       # Kırmızı

    "glasses": (0, 255, 0),     # Yeşil

    "no_glasses": (0, 0, 255)   # Kırmızı

}



while video.isOpened():

    # Acquire frame and resize to expected shape [1xHxWx3]

    ret, frame = video.read()

    if not ret:

        print('Reached the end of the video!')

        break



    frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    frame_resized = cv2.resize(frame_rgb, (width, height))

    input_data = np.expand_dims(frame_resized, axis=0)



    # Normalize pixel values if using a floating model (i.e. if model is non-quantized)

    if floating_model:

        input_data = (np.float32(input_data) - input_mean) / input_std



    # Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input

    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

    interpreter.invoke()



    # Retrieve detection results

    boxes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[boxes_idx]['index'])[0]  # Bounding box coordinates of detected objects

    classes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[classes_idx]['index'])[0]  # Class index of detected objects

    scores = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[scores_idx]['index'])[0]  # Confidence of detected objects



    # Loop over all detections and draw detection box if confidence is above minimum threshold

    for i in range(len(scores)):

        if scores[i] > min_conf_threshold and scores[i] <= 1.0:

            object_name = labels[int(classes[i])]  # Nesnenin etiketini al

            if object_name in label_colors:  # Eşleşen etiket varsa

                # Get bounding box coordinates and draw box

                ymin = int(max(1, (boxes[i][0] * imH)))

                xmin = int(max(1, (boxes[i][1] * imW)))

                ymax = int(min(imH, (boxes[i][2] * imH)))

                xmax = int(min(imW, (boxes[i][3] * imW)))



                # Get the color for the object label

                color = label_colors[object_name]



                # Draw a rectangle around the object with the specified color

                cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), color, 2)



                # Draw label

                label = f'{object_name}: {int(scores[i] * 100)}%'  # Example: 'person: 72%'

                labelSize, baseLine = cv2.getTextSize(label, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, 2)  # Get font size

                label_ymin = max(ymin, labelSize[1] + 10)  # Make sure not to draw label too close to top of window

                cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin, label_ymin - labelSize[1] - 10),

                              (xmin + labelSize[0], label_ymin + baseLine - 10), (255, 255, 255),

                              cv2.FILLED)  # Draw white box to put label text in

                cv2.putText(frame, label, (xmin, label_ymin - 7), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 0),

                            2)  # Draw label text



                if  object_name == 'cofia' in labels and  object_name ==  'glasses' in labels and object_name == 'no_beard' in labels:

                    text = 'YOU CAN PASS'

                    color = (0, 255, 0)  # Yeşil

                

                else:

                    text = 'YOU CAN NOT PASS'

                    color = (255, 255, 0)  # Beyaz veya başka bir renk

                      

                    cv2.putText(frame, text, (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2,cv2.LINE_AA)  # Burası ayrım



    # All the results have been drawn on the frame, so it's time to display it.

    cv2.imshow('Object detector', frame)



    # Press 'q' to quit

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):

        break



# Clean up

video.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```